# Looking for a lightweight theme using WP3 new tags and features (not 2010)

Tags: customization, themes, theme-recommendation

I design & build a lot of bespoke Wordpress themes for clients, and before I just took the best parts out of the default Kubrick and made my own 'vanilla' theme.

The new default, [TwentyTen](http://2010dev.wordpress.com/) is way too complex for my needs, and is a bit kitchen sink.

Are there any lightweight WordPress 3 themes like these? http://designceo.com/20-lightweight-minimalist-wordpress-themes ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a suggestion and not necessarily the answer, but some of those are so basic I'm wondering if using the [Starkers theme](http://starkerstheme.com/) from Elliot Jay Stocks and just adding a bit of style to it, could make the simple theme you've been looking for.

Comment: ah great - that *is* wp3 compatible, but still full of twenty10 junk, and the functions file is massive and incomprehensible!  

It's a good recommendation but still looking for something leaner, thanks!

Comment: Fair point, it is full of twenty10 code, I thought you meant lightweight in terms of design. :-)

Comment: K. I'm going to use it as a starting point anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://standardtheme.com/ -- they just released version 2.0, and from what I've seen it works quite well, whether or not you want to customize it.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Toolbox](http://themeshaper.com/toolbox-html5-starter-theme/)? It is HTML5 based as well.